# Adjusting the p obtained from a Logistic Regression with 50% prevalence of Disease to the population with 10% prevalence

Tags: logistic-regression

I have a question regarding Logistic Regression: My dataset consists of a case-control dataset of 100 sick cases and 100 healthy controls (Both fictitious Gaussian distributions. Thus, the prevalence is 0.5. For simplicity purposes for this query, I am using only one variable (x) and its coefficients B0 and B1.  Using those coefficients and a given value of x, I generate the probability (p) of being sick but only for the dataset with 50% prevalence. However, I want to calculate the p for the population at large, which has a prevalence of Sick = 9%, but I cannot find the way to do it. Could someone here give me a hand?

Comment: As a heads up, “p value” in statistics lingo has a specific meaning. Yes, the p-value is a probability, but it is a very specific probability. The question would benefit from changing the terminology to something like “predicted probability”.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a technique called prevalence adjustment.

Here's how you can calculate the adjusted probability:

1. First, calculate the odds ratio (OR) using the coefficient B1. The odds ratio represents the likelihood of being sick compared to being healthy based on the value of x.
2. Next, calculate the prevalence ratio (PR) by dividing the prevalence of sickness in the population at large (9%) by the prevalence in your dataset (0.5). The prevalence ratio tells us how the prevalence in the population at large compares to the observed dataset.
3. Multiply the odds ratio (OR) by the prevalence ratio (PR) to get the adjusted odds. This takes into account the difference in prevalence between the observed dataset and the population at large.
4. Finally, use the adjusted odds to calculate the adjusted probability (adjusted p) using the logistic function. This gives you the estimated probability of being sick in the population at large with a prevalence of 9%.

Note: Remember that this approach assumes that the relationship between the variable (x) and sickness remains the same in the population at large.

**Edit**

It's no problem at all.

You are right, I meant OR = e^B1

When you have multiple predictors with their respective coefficients (Bn) and predictor values (xn), the logistic regression equation becomes: p = 1 / (1 + exp(-(B0 + B1x1 + B2x2 + ... + Bn*xn)))

Here, x1, x2, ..., xn represent the values of each predictor variable for a given observation. B0 is the intercept term, and B1, B2, ..., Bn are the coefficients associated with each predictor variable.

To calculate the probability (p) for the population at large, you would follow the same steps as mentioned earlier, but now the logistic regression equation will include all the predictor variables and their coefficients.

As for the use of x,I was working with the example you gave in your question. If you want to calculate the probability (p) for the population at large based on the blood test results (x), you would substitute the specific x value into the logistic regression equation along with the adjusted intercept and other coefficients. This will give you the estimated probability of being sick for that particular individual in the population with a prevalence of 9%.
I elaborated on the steps by adding equations:

Train the logistic regression model on your case-control dataset with a prevalence of 50% (100 sick cases and 100 healthy controls). This will give you the estimated coefficients for your predictor variables.

Once you have the coefficients, you can adjust the intercept term to account for the change in prevalence. The intercept term represents the log-odds of the outcome when all predictor variables are zero. In this case, you need to adjust it to reflect the prevalence of 9% sick cases.

To adjust the intercept, you can use the formula:

adjusted_intercept = original_intercept + log((desired_prevalence / (1 - desired_prevalence)) / (original_prevalence / (1 - original_prevalence)))

Here, the original_intercept is the intercept estimated from your logistic regression model with a prevalence of 50% (0.5), and the original_prevalence is 0.5. The desired_prevalence is 0.09 (9%).

Once you have the adjusted_intercept, you can plug it into the logistic regression equation to calculate the new probabilities for the population at large:
p = exp(adjusted_intercept + coefficient_1x_1 + coefficient_2x_2 + ...)

In this equation, x_1, x_2, etc., represent the values of your predictor variables, and coefficient_1, coefficient_2, etc., are the estimated coefficients from your logistic regression model.

Comment: Vinita, in the 1st step: "First, calculate the odds ratio (OR) using the coefficient B1." Do you mean: OR = e^B1 ? Also, how does it work when I have more predictors with their respective Bn, xn? And where does x come into play, because the idea is that a patient is screened, a blood test yields x for the 50% prevalence dataset, but then each x for each patient yields the p for the population at large. Sorry to bother you so much but I have been struggling with this for weeks now. Tx and regards, Ricardo.

Comment: Dear Vinita: Not working: (a) I do not know what am I doing wrong and I would really appreciate an example in which the prevalence adjusted Probability in the Training set is similar to the Probability for the same biomarker concentration in the Population set.
(b) I find it counterintuitive that an equation based on Intercept + Slope * x can yield the same Probability result after adjusting only the Intercept for prevalence.
Since I do not know how to upload files, I am leaving the Word and the Excel files zipped together inside http://oncopet.com/statistics/logistic_regression/lr.zip

Comment: Before opening the Excel file I uploaded, you have to turn off "Automatic calculation" in Excel's Options. Otherwise you get #VALUE all over the place. Sorry about that.